# With YRDropdownView, when I present it after a refresh it gets caught at the top of the screen, and can't be seen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I'm using [YRDropdownView](https://github.com/onemightyroar/YRDropdownView) to present notifications in my app, in this case when they try to manually trigger a data refresh it will notify them that there's no internet (if there isn't).

This refresh is triggered by a pull to refresh gesture (namely the native one Apple introduced in iOS 6) which fires the `refresh` method I have, and in there I check if there's internet. If there's not, I present the notification.

But as the method fires when the user pulls the screen down, the notification appears up there, and only when you scroll up do you see it. How can I attach it more so below the navigation bar?

I'll include whatever code requested, but as of right now I can't think of any that's relevant and this is more of a general purpose question. I just present the notification with the standard method from the github page, and the refresh is the standard refresh controller from iOS 6 on a table view controller.